# Showing user different content after timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a page with a 30 second countdown from when the user loads it. The page should count down from 30 and then hide the timer as it reaches 0.

The `countdown` div should be hidden after 30 seconds and the `reveal` div containing the content to show to the user be shown instead.

```js
let timer = 30;

const interval = setInterval(function() {
  timer--;
  $('.timer').text(timer);
  if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);


$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide('blind', {}, 30000)
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="countdown">
<p class="timer">…</p>
</div>


<div class="reveal">    
<p>Here is the revealed content</p>
</div>
```

Above is my code, the timer is working fine. I'd like it that as it reaches 0 the div for `countdown` is replaced with `reveal` rather than them both being shown at the same time like they are now.

Quite stuck here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `#successMessage` is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. The `.reveal` div is styled to be hidden on load, and once the countdown completes, the `.countdown` div is hidden and the `.reveal` div shown:

```js
let timer = 5;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.timer').text(timer);
});

const interval = setInterval(function() {
  timer--;
  $('.timer').text(timer);
  if (timer < 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $(".countdown").hide()
    $(".reveal").show()
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="countdown">
<p class="timer">…</p>
</div>


<div class="reveal" style="display:none;">    
<p>Here is the revealed content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There's one second before the counter starts, and the counter goes even to -1.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I let the timer go to -1 so that `0` displays for a while. OP can easily change that test to `=0` if they don't want to show `0` as a value.

Comment: @Nick :) between 0 and the content showing - there's an entire second (therefore -1). What about doing `timer <= 0`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan as I say, an easy change for OP to make if that is their desired behaviour. Completely unrelated, went sailing in Croatia last year (out of Marina Agana) and loved it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a finite recursion, use `setTimeout()`, and `toggleClass()` a CSS class `.none`

```js
const reveal = sec => {
  if (!sec) return $('.countdown, .reveal').toggleClass('none');
  $('.timer').text(sec);
  setTimeout(reveal.bind(null, --sec), 1000);
};

reveal(5); // 5 seconds for demo
```

```css
.none {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="countdown"><p class="timer">…</p></div>
<div class="reveal none"><p>Here is the revealed content</p></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```